# How to intercept backend (api) requests at browser level in multi monitor setup

Tags: javascript, http, browser, worker, workbox

Problem:
Assume an application launched in multimonitor. i.e. Application launched in 2 monitors with separate browser instances.
Now each browser instance makes a API call to backend to load the data i.e. http:///loadData

As we see here, there are two requests to backend from separate browser instances but actually both are trying to load same data. This will create unnecessary overhead on backend.

Is there any way we can intercept backend API at browser level and make sure only one request goes to backend. And other browser request will be served from the response.

[image]

Looked into Service worker to handle this scenario. But it is main intent to use for offline mode. And not sure if it handles all the scenarios like intercepting GET/POST requests.

Comment: Not as if you wouldn't have that same problem with two separate browser windows opened on _one_ monitor, is it.

Comment: Even when using workers, you'd still have to be able to differentiate which request came from which instance to begin with. And the instance that is not allowed to make its own request, would still need to get access to the data somehow. Maybe you can use localStorage to establish some sort of "communication" between the two.